# General solution of continuous function-dependent ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a continuous function $f:I\subseteq\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and an ordinary differential equation given by:
$$ y''-xf(x) y' + f(x) y = 0. $$
I'd like to solve this ODE. However, I don't know how to attack the problem and I'd be very pleased if you give me a hint.

***Edit I***   It has been relatively easy to me to figure out that $y_1(x) := x$ satisfies the ode for every function $f$. If $y_2 := u \cdot x$ for some function $u:I\to\mathbb R$, then
$$ 0 = u''x+2u'- x f(x) (u'x+u)+f(x) u x = x u'' + [2-x^2 f(x)]u'$$
and setting $v := u'$
$$ 0 = x v' + [2-x^2 f(x)] v \iff \frac{dv}{v} = [x^2 f(x)-2]\frac{dx}{x} $$
in its "differential form", so
$$ \ln|v(x)| = \int \left(x f(x) - \frac{2}{x}\right) dx = -2 \ln|x|+xF(x)-\int F(s) ds \implies ...$$
where $F:I\to\mathbb R$ is a primitive of $f$. Is this right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The variation of parameters is the correct approach here, since one solution can be guessed. (Without this lucky guess there is no way forward; there is no general method for solving second-order ODEs with variable coefficients.)

Instead of $F$, I would introduce $G$ and antiderivative of $xf(x)$, and use it to express the function $v$ as 
$$v(x) =Ax^{-2}e^{G(x)}$$
where $A$ is an indefinite constant. Sanity check: $$v'(x) = -2Ax^{-3}e^{G(x)}+Ax^{-1}f(x)e^{G(x)}=(xf(x)-2x^{-1})v(x)$$ as expected.

So, the general solution is 
$$
u(x) = Ax\int x^{-2}e^{G(x)}\,dx+Bx
$$
which is as far as we can go.